# Google Map Marker from GeoCode a little off

Tags: javascript, html, maps

I am pulling is lat long points from a database, combine them, then use reverse lookup to place markers on my map. All the markers get placed on the map, but they are just a little off. I then go to maps.google.com and place the points into the search bar and they work perfectly. Any suggestions? Thank you! The funciton is below:

```
   var lat = resultP[i].get("lat");
   var log = resultP[i].get("long");
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, log);
   geocoder.geocode( { 'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  } //end else
```

Comment: What did you mean by a little off ?

Comment: For example, lat is 42.476185 and log is -96.363533 then I run geocoder.geocode and my lat and log become 42.4766488,-96.36351719999999 (results[0].geometry.location)

Comment: I have been working on this and it seems like my marker get rendered on the nearest road. I am trying to place a marker on a tennis court/softball field. How do I keep the marker from going to the nearest road? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I misunderstood something, but I don't see why you need to geocode the coordinates.

Geocoding is the process of turning an address into coordinates, or the other way around. You don't need to geocode your coordinates if you already have them. The whole point of geocoding is to put them on the nearest road.

To display a marker on the map you can just skip the geocoding and do this:

```
var lat = resultP[i].get("lat");
var log = resultP[i].get("long");
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, log);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng 
});
```